# Modify string variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable for the string `tag:some text` that is stored in a cell. How can I modify the string that is stored in the variable so that it is interpreted as `tag:\"some text\"` (retaining the escape characters)?

Solution: `s = Left(s, 4) & "\" & Chr(34) & Right(s, Len(s) - 4) & Chr(34)`

Comment: Stored where/how for what purpose?

Comment: `s = "tag:\""some text\"""`

Comment: Use `ChrW` because Unicode is the native character set in VB4\5\6\A\Script, JavaScript, Java, .NET, … text data types and in the Windows API and filesystem. The behavior of `Chr` depends on settings that vary by computer, user and time.

Answer (score 0):

use chr(34) to append the quote to the string

```
dim s as string
s = "tag:\" & Chr(34) & "some text\" & Chr(34)
```

Comment: The string is stored in a cell, so I need to modify whatever string is stored in the variable.

Comment: if the cell was A1, you could assign the cell.value to the variable s.  for example: s = cells(1,1).value and you can put the converted s variable back in the cell using cells(1,1).value = s

Comment: I still cannot put `\"` after `tag:`.

Comment: if I use the following code, it puts the new string in cell A1:
Cells(1, 1).Value = s

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely understanding the question, but it seems that you are trying to make a string "some text" into "\"some text\""? If so, you can use CHR(34) as the double quotes. so it would look like

```
"\" & CHR(34) & "some text\" & CHR(34)
```

Comment: The string is stored in a cell, so I need to modify whatever string is stored in the variable.

Comment: okay, so string = "\" & CHR(34) & Cells(row, column).Value & CHR(34)

Comment: That will put `\"` before `tag:`.

Comment: if that is always going to be a leading 4 characters in the string you can use [LEFT()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php) and [RIGHT()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php) functions to get only the first 4 characters and then everything from 5 to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Double Quotes are escaped by adding an extra Double Quotes or using `Chr(34)`, the ascii char number for a Double Quote.

I usually build my strings in the Immediate Window

> ```
> "tag:""some text"""
> "tag:" & Chr(34) & "some text" & Chr(34)
> ```

If I have to escape many double quotes copy the string to the Clipboard and process it there:

```
With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    .GetFromClipboard
    .SetText Replace(.GetText, Chr(34), String(2, 34))
    .PutInClipboard
End With
```

[image]